# How do I make this menu collapse on page load?

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll, drop-down-menu

This is my code. How can I make this menu always be popped out, not just when you click on '#projects'? Change the .click function to what?

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

$.fn.longDropdown = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.longDropdown.defaults, options);

```
// Weird bug to show the correct number of items
opts.visible = (opts.visible + 1);

return this.each(function() {

    // Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
    // $(".dropdown > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
    //     $(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='images/down-arrow.png' />");
    // });

    $(".dropdown > li").click(function() {

            var $container = $(this),
                $list = $container.find('ul'),
                $anchor = $container.find('a'),

                height = $list.height() * 1.0,

                totalHeight = $container.height() * opts.visible,

                containerOffset = $container.offset().top + $container.height(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height(),

                maxHeight = windowHeight - containerOffset;

            if( totalHeight > maxHeight ) {
                while( $container.height() * opts.visible > maxHeight ) {
                    opts.visible = (opts.visible - 1);
                }
                totalHeight = $container.height() * (opts.visible + 1);
            }

            var multiplier = height / totalHeight;

            // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
            $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

            // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
            $anchor.addClass("hover");

            // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
            $list
                .show()
                .css({
                    paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
                });

            // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
            if (multiplier > 1) {
                $container
                    .css({
                        height: totalHeight,
                        overflow: "hidden"
                    })
                    .mousemove(function(e) {
                        var offset = $container.offset();
                        var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * (multiplier)) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                        if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                            $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                        };
                    }); 

            }
        }, function() {
            var $el = $(this);

            // put things back to normal
            $el
                .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
                .find("ul")
                .css({ top: 0 })
                .hide()
                .end()
                .find("a")
                .removeClass("hover");

            opts.visible = (opts.visible + 1);
        })
        .filter(':has(ul)')
        .each(function() {
            $(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='" + opts.image + "' />");
        });

});
```

};

// default options
$.fn.longDropdown.defaults = {
    visible: 4,
    image: 'images/down-arrow.png'
};

})(jQuery);

Thank you.

Comment: How do we know what environment/platform/toolkit you are using? There is no indication of that in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's jQuery, I got the script from here: http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

Comment: Maybe I should do it in the CSS, but I can't get it to work. It needs to be always opened up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take the anonymous function inside `$(".dropdown > li").click()` and name it, then call it on document load? Something like this:

1) Give the function a name:

```
 function expandMenu($container) {
  if (typeof $container=='undefined') $container= $(this);
  $list = $container.find('ul'),
  $anchor = $container.find('a'),

   . . . . 
   Rest of the function body
   . . . .
}
```

2) Bind the function to elements for clicking AND trigger on document load:

```
$(".dropdown > li").click(expandMenu);

AND

$(document).ready(function() {
 expandMenu($('#id_of_auto_expand_menu'));
});
```

Something *like* this should work - that is, refactoring the function.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I can't get it to work. Here is the page, on the upper right side the scroll menu should be always visible: http://onomadesign.com/wordpress/portfolio/identity-design

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: $($('#projects').click());

Comment: Looking back at it. I mistyped it.

$(function() {
    $('#projects').click();
  });

place it anywhere in the javascript. 

the $(function) executes when the document is loaded and ready to be manipulated.

Comment: it makes sense.. but it still doesn't work, tried it everywhere. could you firebug my page (http://onomadesign.com/wordpress/identity-design) to see if you can get it to work? Much appreciated

Comment: I looked at your page and the div you are interested in is:
$('#sub_menu').click()